# How to change value of existing item's string in wxPython ObjectListView list_ctrl

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview-python

I know I can use `list_ctrl.GetStringValueAt()` like so to get the value for a particular object in the `ObjectListView`:

```
class myOLV(ObjectListView):
    ... code to handle specific events

class myPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.list_ctrl = myOLV(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.setColumns()

        # . . .

        self.submit_button = wx.Button(self, label="Submit")
        # ... add to sizer here, skipping tedious stuff in this example
        self.submit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSubmit)

    def setColumns(self):
        self.list_ctrl.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Column 1", "left", 128, "col1"),
            ColumnDefn("Column 2", "left", 128, "col2"),
            ColumnDefn("Column 3", "left", 128, "col3")
        )]

    def onSubmit(self, event):
        objects = self.list_ctrl.GetObjects()
        for obj in objects:
            col1 = self.list_ctrl.GetStringValueAt(obj, 1)
            # how could I change the above value here?
            col2 = self.list_ctrl.GetStringValueAt(obj, 2)
            col3 = self.list_ctrl.GetStringValueAt(obj, 3)
```

But what if I want to change the value of a string given the obj in this current loop and column index? The documentation doesn't seem to have a method that takes the current object and a column index as a parameter, so how could I do this (without removing and repopulating the element)?

I see from [the docs](http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/majorClasses.html#objectlistview-class) that there is a `SetValue(modelObjects, preserveSelection=False)` method but it sets the list of modelObjects to be displayed by the control, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Is there a `SetStringValueAt(modelObject, columnIndex)` method or workaround to do the same thing in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn on cell "editability" by setting your ObjectListView instance's `cellEditMode`. Something like this would work:

```
self.list_ctrl.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK
```

The ObjectListView documentation talks about this here:

- http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/cellEditing.html (old docs)
- http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellEditing.html (new docs)

I also mention it in the following tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

**UPDATE:** Iterating over objects and changing them programmatically is a bit trickier. Fortunately, ObjectListView provides `RefreshObject`, which allows us to change a specific object and then refresh it. Here's an example script:

```
# OLVcheckboxes.py

import wx
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

########################################################################
class Results(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, tin, zip_code, plus4, name, address):
        """Constructor"""
        self.tin = tin
        self.zip_code = zip_code
        self.plus4 = plus4
        self.name = name
        self.address = address


########################################################################
class ProvPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.columns = {0: 'tin',
                        1: 'zip_code',
                        2: 'plus4',
                        3: 'name',
                        4: 'address'}

        self.test_data = [Results("123456789", "50158", "0065", "Patti Jones",
                                  "111 Centennial Drive"),
                          Results("978561236", "90056", "7890", "Brian Wilson",
                                  "555 Torque Maui"),
                          Results("456897852", "70014", "6545", "Mike Love",
                                  "304 Cali Bvld")
                          ]
        self.resultsOlv = ObjectListView(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.resultsOlv.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK

        self.setResults()

        self.column_cbo = wx.ComboBox(self, value='tin',
                                      choices=self.columns.values())
        modify_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Modify Column 1 Cells')
        modify_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onModify)

        mainSizer.Add(self.resultsOlv, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(self.column_cbo, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(modify_btn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onModify(self, event):
        """
        Modify cells
        """
        objects = self.resultsOlv.GetObjects()
        column = self.column_cbo.GetValue()
        for obj in objects:
            value = 'Row #%s' % self.resultsOlv.GetIndexOf(obj)
            setattr(obj, column, value)
            self.resultsOlv.RefreshObject(obj)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setResults(self):
        """"""
        self.resultsOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("TIN", "left", 100, "tin"),
            ColumnDefn("Zip", "left", 75, "zip_code"),
            ColumnDefn("+4", "left", 50, "plus4"),
            ColumnDefn("Name", "left", 150, "name"),
            ColumnDefn("Address", "left", 200, "address")
        ])
        self.resultsOlv.CreateCheckStateColumn()
        self.resultsOlv.SetObjects(self.test_data)


########################################################################
class ProvFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        title = "OLV Checkbox Tutorial"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title=title, size=(1024, 768))
        panel = ProvPanel(self)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ProvFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I actually have that line, but I want to edit it programmatically, not through a user action, but while iterating through each object. How do I do it given the object and a specified column?

Comment: This answer only seems to work for allowing the user to edit the field via clicking in it. My question asks how to do this within my code while iterating through the objects.

Comment: I updated with a code example that demonstrates one way to do it programmatically as well

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!